# Using curl with --data-urlencode and fetching the content in django

Tags: python, django, unix, curl

I have a file, and I need to send its contents to a function. What I am currently doing is as follows:

```
$ curl --data-urlencode "$( cat my_file.xml)" MyIP

# in function
def receiver(request):
    print request.POST
```

This returns something like:

```
<QueryDict: {u'\ufeff<?xml version ': [u' "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>\n<Orders>\n ...</Orders>']}>
```

In other words, the `curl` command is correctly sending the data to the django function; however, it is not easily retrievable since the POST data is split up between the request.POST key (`u'\ufeff

In addition the xml file is **not** properly url-encoded, so I don't think I can use `curl -d @file`.

It seems to be taking `'\ufeff<?xml version '` as the QueryDict key. How would I pass the file contents here and retrieve it as a single string so I can parse the xml?

Comment: My Bad: I misread your question. You should rewrite it. I guess you are asking how django can process a file sent to it using curl post command. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, I'll rewrite it to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very easy (hack) solution for this, use string concatenation on the `request.POST` dict to re-combine the information:

```
contents = request.POST.keys()[0] + "=" + request.POST.values()[0]
```